# The PathVariable can't be 9 in spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I wrote code like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/node")
public class NodeController {
    @GetMapping("/extend/{id}")
    public HttpResult extendNode(@PathVariable int id) {
        return new HttpResult(nodeService.extendNode(id));
    }

    /*some other methods*/
}
```

When id was 1,2,3..., that's ok. but when id was 9, this method won't work.
I'm sure there is not a method with the path "/node/extend/9".

I slept and the problem has gone. sigh.

So the problem is the browser cache, got it.

Comment: It may help to see the code of `nodeService`, especially from method `extendNode(int id)`. Do you get any Exception or error ? Then please add this message to your post together with the missing code.

Comment: @hc_dev Thank you for advice. but I put a breakpoint in the method of the controller and the program didn't stop there. And this problem don't appear now, so I'm sure there is nothing wrong with `nodeService`